# Is this usage correct? “versions N and prior”

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

Or is this correct "version N and prior"?

Mainly, I'm asking about this because in

> **version** N and prior

I think that "versions" are implied by *prior*, hence one would read it as

> version N and *[versions]* prior

while in the first example

> **versions** N and prior

the usage of "versions" is incorrect since after this we have direct *one version*.

First example could be corrected to

> versions: X and prior

however, without ":" it looks incorrect to me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Both are grammatically and semantically correct. You can use either to convey nearly identical meanings.

Comment: Just for the record, it may be more fluid to say "Versions prior to N+1".

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Altho' "prior to" strictly is ambiguous and excludes the limit, it is at risk of being used or understood incorrectly, and I would suggest avoiding its use in this context.

Comment: @TrevorD, I think you mean "unambiguous".

Answer (score 1):

I think either usage would be correct, but I would lean towards "*versions*" for clarity.

Another example is this:

Suppose you had four boxes, marked A, B, C and D. Two of the boxes contain prizes, the other two are empty. You might say

> boxes A and B both contain a prize

or

> boxes C and D are empty

In each case you are referring to a group of *boxes*, so you would use the plural form of *box*.

You could read

> Version X and prior

as

> Version X and prior [versions]

The word *versions* is implied in this case. This may be idiomatic rather than strictly grammatical, but I think the reader would understand.

Regarding the colon, it wouldn't be correct to use it within a sentence, but would be fine in a list.

Answer (score 0):

If I read:

> Version N and prior

I would actually read it as:

> Version N and prior [versions]

rather than (as you suggest) as:

> Version N and [versions] prior

With that in mind, I would say that *Version N* should be singular.
Personally, I would probably use "earlier" instead of "prior":

> Version N and earlier [versions]

But the easiest solution to overcome the issue of whether to use singular or plural, is to abbreviate *Version(s)* to *Ver.*:

> Ver. N & earlier

You do not say in what context you are planning to use this expression, but I'm making the (perhaps rash) assumption that it is in some kind of programming context. If that's correct - and although I wouldn't want to belittle the need to use the singular and plural forms correctly - I would suggest that, in that context, your readers are not likely to give the matter a second thought, if indeed they even notice the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I'm thinking without the 's' is correct. [This forum post talking about adjectives](http://www.englishforums.com/English/AdjectivesNounsPlural/cvmxn/post.htm) states,

> The simple rule is that the form of adjective doesn't change based on gender, number, and tense.

And [this blog post](http://david-crystal.blogspot.com/2010/05/on-plural-adjectives.html) says,

> As a teacher, I have always taught the rule that there are no plural adjectives in English

Although the second article goes on to say American English neglects to pluralize adjectives while British English does, and how American English is slowly picking it up.

So my vote is the word, 'version' is being used as an adjective to describe the different software packages and therefore should be treated as such, in this case, without the pluralization.

Comment: That's an interesting answer, but I don't think it's correct. I don't think the word "version" is used as an adjective in this case.